# How to get all files like: js,css,images from a website to save it for offline use?

Tags: javascript, php, python, angularjs, web

I am not talking about the softwares like surf online, HTtrack, or any other 'save page' feature of browsers but I need to know how actually it happens in the background. I am interested in making my own program to do that.

Also is it possible to do in JavaScript. If yes what are the libraries I should look into or any other APIs that could be helpful. Please give me any kind of information about the topic I couldn't find any relevant thing to contribute my research.

Comment: One word : wget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download entire HTML content of the web page
- For JS files, look for the `<script>` tags and download the js file using the `src` attribute or any inline scripts inside the tag
- For CSS, use `<link>` tag to download the CSS file and also look for any `<style>` tags for inline CSS styling
- For Images, scan for `<img>` tag and download the image using `src` attribute

Same approach can be used for audio/video etc